# Getting text-to-speech working and connecting it to java

Tags: java, html, text-to-speech

Ok so I have an artificial intelligence system running on my Mac through terminal, on localhost with java. I want to make my ai speak without flash. There is an HTML tag that could be easily plugged into a tts script, but I don't want to output an mp3 file, I want to output an audio tag with autoplay and hidden so that it seems every time you get a response from the ai, it will speak too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google translate TTS implemented as a servlet would solve this problem, I think.  [See this implementation](http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/HowtoBlogs.xhtml?b=757). That is of course if you don't mind installing Tomcat or equivalent.

The problem is, until when will Google Translate TTS be free?

Comment: thanks, i found that part too and i mad this html, it could help you too, `<audio id="audio" onended="document.forms[0].elements[0].focus();" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=<?php echo $say ?>" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>`

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about the JavaSpeech API and, for example, the [FreeTTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php) implementation?

Comment: ive tried using it but it just wont work on mac, it keeps referring to a file called demo that is not in the download

Comment: well it has taken countless hours of googling but i have given up on freetts and tried googles speech program, i have come up with this tag that worked, `<source src="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=><response/>" type="audio/mpeg" />
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>`

Comment: @Ernest thanks i worked hard on it, you can replace the ><response/> part with anything, that was how the java response would translate in my case but it works with php echo too